# Node.js execute Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a completely newbie question and I'm sure the solution is very easy but I don't get it.

I downloaded Node.js and put the command-tool file and the npm in my project file.

I created a file called example.js which contains

```
console.log("hello world");
```

Now I open the node file and type in

```
node example.js
```

And it shows me unexpected Identifier.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
 node -v
```

Shows node is not defined ?? ..
I'm slightly confused.

Edit2: MAC IOS

Edit3: I installed it and the path was usr/local/bin  am I allowed to just move the file?

Edit4: Thanks node -v works now. I opened it through the cmd tool

Edit5: okay now everything works.. I thought I have to work with the node cmd tool. Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Can you show the full error message? Also what does `node -v` say? And which operating system do you have?

Comment: You either do not have Node.js installed, or your OS is not finding it.

Comment: As I'm reading your question it seem like you added `node example.js` in a file (which is why you get unexpected indentifier), `node example.js` should be typed in your shell.
Open a terminal and issue that command from the directory in which you have the file.

Comment: I think you have to be somwhat more specific? If you open the node file and type `node example.js` you would get an `unexpected identifier` error as it's not valid javascript, you have to open a command line window and type `node example.js` ?

Comment: Open new terminal ( run-> cmd ) and then try "node /example.js"

Comment: have to installed the node `globally` using `-g` option. otherwise you will have specify the path  to node command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open terminal
2. Go to the folder you have your example.js (use `cd`-command)
3. type in terminal `node example.js`, press `enter`

You should not RUN node before typing `node example.js`